# Multiple aligning symbols

Tags: align

I would like to do the closest thing there is to opening an align* environment inside another align* environment. In other words: it would be great if there were an environment, call it Align, that allows you to use to symbols to align equations in math mode using a specified number of aligning symbols &1, &2, ..., &n. For example something that works like this:

```
\begin{Align*}[2] &1 1=1 \\ &1 4 &2= 2+2 \\ &2 = 1+1+1+1 \\ &1 7 = 7 \end{Align*}
```

which I would want to look like

```
1 = 1
4 = 2+2 =
  = 1+1+1+1
7=7
```

Does there exist such an environment?

I tried looking in [this](http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf) guide but I couldn't find anything, and I'm just a beginner... thanks for any help!

Comment: The [amsmath package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) provides lots of useful environments for equations. Have a look at `alignat`.

Comment: I had heard of alignat but it doesn't seem to have multiple symbols and I also couldn't find the documentation. If someone answers the question using alignat to show me how to write my (stupid) example I would be very grateful :D

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! No, there isn't. Maybe if you make a more significant example we could suggest something good. Nice to meet another Italian mathematician!

Comment: Is something like `\begin{alignat*}{3}
1 &= 1 \4 &= 2+2     &&=\  &= 1+1+1+1 &&=4\7 &=7
\end{alignat*}` yield what you are looking for?

Comment: @PeterGrill Yes, thank you! I guess alignat is what I was looking for. Does anybody know where to find documentations for this environment (I still don't quite understand it from the example).

Comment: @Emilio: if you use TeX Live, you can run `texdoc amsmath` in a terminal to get the `amsmath` documentation. Following the link that Ian Thompson provided in his comment, you will also find (at the bottom of the page) links to the `amsmath`'s documentation in several languages.

Comment: @egreg Thanks :D I didn't paste the part of code I was working on because it is quite long, and what I wanted to achieve is really similar to the numerical example I wrote. Basically I wanted to write a list, aligning each element of the list vertically, and expanding each one into a series of equations. If I just used align, and & for the = signs then the elements of the list (in this case 1, 4, 7) wouldn't be aligned any more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only have a single alignment position, a regular `align` would suffice. For multiple alignment positions, use `alignat`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{3}
  1 &= 1             \\
  4 &= 2+2     & &=  \\
    &= 1+1+1+1 & &=4 \\
  7 &= 7
\end{alignat*} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `alignat` environment allows you to specify the number of alignment positions.

Herbert's [`mathmode` document](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/obsolete/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) provides some informative examples on the different [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) environments and usage. Specifically, see **Part II `amsmath` package** (p 43). An example of your output request is on p 46.