# Align formulas independently nested

Tags: math-mode, align, amsmath

I have the formula

[image]

which I create with the code

```
\begin{align}
\WKernSub[\x]{sub} &\defas \bigsumshort \sum_{j=1\ |\ j\in\J}^{\card\Ob} \mhsp \frac{\massSub[j]{subA}}{\sqrt{ (2\m\pi\m\gwp)^{\nbFeat} }} \m \exp{ \frac{    \left(\x-\ob[j]\right)^\trnsp \m \left(\x-\ob[j]\right)   }{-2 \m \gwp} }  \mhspE,
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\J = \big\{\mhsp l \mhsp\big|\mhsp      &(  \ob\in\Obrd \AND l=i  ) \\
                                    \OR &(  \ob\in\Obru \AND \ob[l]\in\Obvd \AND \ob[l]\primderL\ob[i]  ) \mhsp\big\}  \mhspE,  \nn
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\WFctSub[\x]{sub} &\defas \bigsumshort \sum_{j=1\ |\ \ob[j]\in\Obr}^{\card\Ob} \WKernSub[\x]{sub} \label{eq:WKernSub}
\end{align}
```

What I would like is, to have the formulas aligned such, that the = and := are aligned. I do not want to have the alignment of the second formula touched. I did checkout [Alignment across nested aligned environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68547/alignment-across-nested-aligned-environments), but I was not able to transfer this to my problem and [Multiple aligning symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54285/multiple-aligning-symbols). I don't want to "open" a new column for alignments.

How can I achieve this?

A minimal working example would be (other symbols):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
W_{sub,i} &= asdf
\end{align}

\begin{align}
J = \big\{ l \quad\big|\quad    &(  o \in O ) \nonumber\\
                    \vee\quad   &(  o \in O \wedge o \in O  ) \big\}  , \nonumber
\end{align}

\begin{align}
W_{sub} &= some long formula without any meaning
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

resulting in

[image]

Comment: I see no formula 0.3 in the top picture.

Comment: note that despite the "resulting in", the image presumably was not made from the posted code (equation numbers formatted differently and wider text block)

Comment: @egreg: Sorry, typo. I corrected it.

Comment: an `align` that contains only one line is *never* going to align with anything else.  only when multiple lines are present in an `align` (or `alignat`) environment are they going to interact.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Yes, and I would like to know how to do it. Simply putting everything into the align does not work, because I need multiple &s. I am just trying to explain, what I want, I am not claiming that I would expect this to be the answer.

Comment: `align` can have multiple `&`

Comment: please see my answer using a single `align` with a nested `aligned`.  it took quite a long time to prepare, since i had to guess at the definition of your macros; several of them are obviously not what you had in mind, but it's the best i could do unless i had unlimited time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a kludge.  it would have been much easier had you provided the definitions
of the macros you used.  the definitions and other coding here is just an
approximation.

like david's answer, this nests an `aligned` block within the main alignment.
the definition of the `:=` is jiggered a bit to improve its alignment relative
to that of the simple `=` signs.

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\card}{\#}
\newcommand{\defas}{\;\mathrel{\!\!{:}{=}\,}}
\newcommand{\bigsumshort}{}
\newcommand{\gwp}{\omega}
\newcommand{\J}{\mathcal{J}}
\newcommand{\Ob}{\mathcal{O}}
\newcommand{\Obr}{\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{r}}}
\newcommand{\Obrd}{\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{rd}}}
\newcommand{\Obru}{\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{ru}}}
\newcommand{\ob}{\bm{o}_{i}}
\newcommand{\m}{\cdot}
\newcommand{\mhsp}{}
\newcommand{\mhspE}{\;}
\newcommand{\massSub}[1]{m_{\mathrm{subA,v,#1}}}
\newcommand{\nbFeat}{F}
\newcommand{\trnsp}{\top}
\newcommand{\x}{\bm{x}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\mathbf{W}_{\mathrm{sub}j} (\bm{x})
 &\defas \bigsumshort \sum_{j=1\ |\ j\in\J}^{\card\Ob} \mhsp
  \frac{\massSub{j}}{\sqrt{ (2\m\pi\m\gwp)^{\nbFeat} }} \m
  \exp \left( \frac{    \left(\x-\ob[j]\right)^\trnsp \m \left(\x-\ob[j]\right)   }{-2 \m \gwp} \right) \mhspE,\\
%
J &= \bigl\{ l \; \bigl| \;
           \begin{aligned}[t]
                  &( \ob \in \Obrd \wedge l = i ) \\
               \mathllap{\vee\,}   &( \ob \in \Obru \wedge \ob \in \Obrd
               \wedge \ob \leftarrow \ob  ) \bigr| \bigr\}  ,
           \end{aligned} \nonumber\\
%\J &= \big\{\mhsp l \mhsp\big|\mhsp      &(  \ob\in\Obrd \AND l=i  ) \\
%%                                    \OR &(  \ob\in\Obru \AND \ob[l]\in\Obvd \AND \ob[l]\primderL\ob[i]  ) \mhsp\big\}  \mhspE,  \nn\\
%
\mathbf{WF}_{\mathrm{sub}}(\x) &\defas \bigsumshort \sum_{j=1\ |\ \ob[j]\in\Obr}^{\card\Ob} \mathbf{W}_{\mathrm{sub}j}(\x) \label{eq:WKernSub}\\
%
W_{sub,i} &= asdf\\
%
W_{sub} &= some long formula without any meaning
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Comment: the problem of fitting this into the narrow width of a two-column page is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Easier than some of Knuth's exercises in *The Art of Computer Programming* ;o)

Comment: The commands to create the symbols are hundreds of lines of code. They are not simply created with single command, but build on further commands, which build on further commands, etc. My Symbols.sty file has 1057 lines of code. Its the only way to handle the number of symbols I have.

Answer (score 3):

I's use a nested `aligned` (It is best never to have one math display following another, TeX doesn't really try to space that correctly)

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
W_{\mathrm{sub},i} &= asdf\\
&\begin{aligned}
J = \big\{ l \quad\big|\quad    &(  o \in O ) \nonumber\\
                    \vee\quad   &(  o \in O \wedge o \in O  ) \big\}  , \nonumber
\end{aligned}\\
W_{\mathrm{sub}} &= some long formula without any meaning
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: now the J is aligned with the other two =. Can we align them on the =s?

Comment: @Make42 well yes of course, just move the `J=` before the `&\begin{aligned}` but I read your question as saying explicitly that you didn't want the middle terms aligned with the `W_..=` terms.

Comment: That was a misunderstanding. Probably because of the typo I corrected.